# automatically populate row data from multiple sheets using single function in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an **All Projects Net Profit** sheet with a dataset of project information which will continue to get bigger with new entries and is as follows:

[image: Dataset]

For each project I have a separate sheet based on the **Project Name** that calculates the costings and overall net profit (see sample data at the bottom for the **Project 1** sheet).

To the right of the above dataset on the **All Projects Net Profit** sheet, I have a formula that copies the monthly net profit from each project.

This function also allows the project to be terminated on a specific date, determined by the associated row in column E, or alternatively excluded altogether if the same row in Column F is set to Yes. This will be used as a way to quickly see what happens to the financial picture if a project is cancelled on a set date or simply doesn't start as intended, without affecting the source data.

[image: Net Profit]

The formula I have used in K2 is as follows:

```
=LET(StartOfMonths, $K$1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($K$1),COLUMN($K$1)+ StudioProjectedOperatingMonths -1)),
ProjectNetProfitData, INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!$I$1:$XX$13"),
TerminateProjectEarly, NOT(ISBLANK($E2)),
ExcludeProject, EXACT($F2, "Yes"),
NetProfitRowIndex, 13,
SetRowToZeros, SEQUENCE(1,StudioProjectedOperatingMonths,0,0),
IFERROR(IF(ExcludeProject,SetRowToZeros,IF(TerminateProjectEarly,HLOOKUP(IF(StartOfMonths<=$E2,StartOfMonths, 0), ProjectNetProfitData,NetProfitRowIndex,FALSE),HLOOKUP(IF(StartOfMonths,StartOfMonths, 0), ProjectNetProfitData,NetProfitRowIndex,FALSE))),0))
```

Where :

**StartOfMonths** is the date range from K1 (August 2017) to **StudioProjectedOperatingMonths** (defined as 401)

**ProjectNetProfitData** is the dataset on the project sheet (uses A2 for sheet name)

**TerminateProjectEarly** Only include Net Profit before this date

**ExcludeProject** Do not include any Net Profit for the project if set

**NetProfitRowIndex** 13 is the row to reference from **ProjectNetProfitData**

To get this to work for all rows I have duplicacted the function in to K3, K4, K5 and K6. Although this all works as expected, I'd ideally have a single function in K2 that will automatically fill the rows based on the entries from A2 down, such that the end user doesn't need to copy functions down the sheet in the K column.

I believe something like BYCOL can help me achieve this but I'm a little stumped on how to apply it in this case.

Any ideas on how I can modify the above function to work in this way?

**Project 1** sheet Net Profit sample data (doesn't include unnecessary rows - only row 13, all other projects follow the same layout but with different date ranges):

|  | Sep-17 | Oct-17 | Nov-17 | Dec-17 | Jan-18 | Feb-18 | Mar-18 | Apr-18 | May-18 | Jun-18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monthly Net Profit | £81,604 | 81604 | £81,604.00 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 |

**All Projects Net Profit** sheet dataset:

| Project Name | Project Code Name | Start Date | End Date | Project Termination Date | Exclude From P&L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Project 1 Code Name | 01/09/2017 | 31/03/2023 |  | No |
| Project 2 | Project 2 Code Name | 01/02/2020 | 31/12/2022 |  | No |
| Project 3 | Project 3 Code Name | 01/03/2020 | 31/12/2021 |  | No |
| Project 4 | Project 4 Code Name | 01/04/2020 | 30/06/2021 |  | No |
| Project 5 | Project 5 Code Name | 01/01/2023 | 31/12/2024 |  | No |

**Final Solution to Question**

Final solution with the much needed help of David Leal supporting the Project Termination Date and the Net Profit data across separate sheets:

```
    =LET(dataset, FILTER(A2:F999,(A2:A999<>"")),
prjName, FILTER(dataset,{1,0,0,0,0,0}),
exclude, FILTER(dataset,{0,0,0,0,0,1}),
incProj, FILTER(prjName, exclude="No"),
terminationDate, FILTER(dataset,{1,0,0,0,1,0}),
datesProf, I1:BD1,
GET_TERMINATION_DATE, LAMBDA(proj, VLOOKUP(proj, terminationDate,2,FALSE)),
 GET_DATES, LAMBDA(proj, INDIRECT("'"&proj&"'!B1#")),
 GET_PROFIT,LAMBDA(proj, LET(dates, INDIRECT("'"&proj&"'!B1#"),
  INDIRECT("'"&proj&"'!B3:"&ADDRESS(3,MAX(COLUMN(dates)))))),
DROP(REDUCE("", prjName,
    LAMBDA(ac,p, VSTACK(ac, N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(p, incProj))) *
        XLOOKUP(datesProf,GET_DATES(p)*(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(GET_TERMINATION_DATE(p))), GET_DATES(p)<= GET_TERMINATION_DATE(p),1)), GET_PROFIT(p),0)))),1))
```

Comment: Please try to simplify and isolate the problem, you are using named variable in your formula that we can not reproduce it. The input data doesn't have information on how to calculate the project net profit.

Comment: Hi @DavidLeal I've modified the explanation and included sample data.

Comment: What is the logic if the projects ends in the middle of the month for considering the net profit for a given month? Do we need to take that into consideration from All Projects Net Profit sheet?

Comment: I'm assuming the Project Termination Date will be the end of the month, I don't need anything more accurate for now as this is high level what ifs. I'll take a look at your suggestion below, although I will need to find a way for the formula to cut the project short based on the Project Termination Date though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following approach in cell `H2`:

```
=LET(incProj, FILTER(A2:A6, E2:E6="No"), prjProf, G2:G3, datesProf, H1:O1,
  prj, A10:A11, dates, B9:K9, profit, B10:K11, DROP(REDUCE("", prjProf, 
  LAMBDA(ac,p, VSTACK(ac, N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(p, incProj))) *
      XLOOKUP(datesProf,dates, FILTER(profit, prj=p),0)))),1))
```

Here is the output:

[image: excel output]

it generates all at once the rows and columns. Please adjust it to your real problem and confirm the result. The start and end dates of the project are not considered. It only takes into account the **Exclude** column from that table. Defined some names via `LET` for easier reading the formula.

**Note**: Since we are using `XLOOKUP` function, `dates` and `profit` need to have the same number of columns.

Comment: Hi David, just getting around to re-visiting this so apologies for the delay. To test the above with my data I’d need the profit and dates from your let to be on different sheets, so a sheet called Project 1 with a date row and a profit row and another sheet called Project 2 with a date row and profit row. Is this possible with this set up - I used INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!$I$1:$XX$13"), to reference the other sheet?

Additionally I’d need to be able to have the Project Termination Date end the project early, in a similar way to my original non spill solution, is this possible with this method?

Comment: yes, you can as per my knowledge, you need to try in your real problem. We usually here respond to sample problem, not the real one.

Comment: Hi David, I have created a sample project and created a test as above which works fine (barring the ability to stop the revenue of a project on a termination date). However, my question requires the formula to work on the data across multiple sheets. In the sample project I have created two versions, one with data on multiple sheets. Is there a way I can share the sheet for reference?

Comment: I adjusted the formula to cater for the net profit being on different sheets and changed the profit filter (since it's not a table in the same sheet) to the defined profit, however this is just spilling the data for Project 1: `=LET(incProj, FILTER(A2:A6, F2:F6="No"),
prjProf, A2:A6,
datesProf, I1:AF1,
prj, A2:A6,
dates, INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!$B$1:$X$1"),
profit, INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!$B$2:$X$2"),
DROP(REDUCE("", prjProf,
  LAMBDA(ac,p, VSTACK(ac, N(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(p, incProj))) *
      XLOOKUP(datesProf,dates, profit,0)))),1))`

Comment: share the link here, let's see what I can do

Comment: Please find the workbook here : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mqryhp3c26axmm/Spill%20Net%20Profit%20Data.xlsx?dl=0). I would really need the  Project Termination Date to work for my needs too. Columns C and D are only there for reference (copied from elsewhere in my original data) so I can ensure any use of the Project Termination Date falls within them.

Comment: I was trying to keep the same logic of the initial formulation, maybe it can be simplified, but I guess it works. Check the tab **Multiple Sheets** in the following [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlZxw2GG3C7Ih3N1o9blcQ5PaA7y?e=8w6FA8). Formula is in `I2`. You need to assume all sheets have the key information (dates and profit) in the same range. Please verify

Comment: Worked great! I made some modifications to use the Project Termination Date (restricted to full months as this is all I need) and also support the addition of further projects. I don't have the room to paste the formula but it can be found here on sheet **UnlimitedDataset** in cell I2 [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9mqryhp3c26axmm/Spill%20Net%20Profit%20Data.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Got a slight issue with the formula when moving in to my real data. The real data has variable ranges of dates for the net profit data. I tried modifying to `GET_PROFIT,LAMBDA(proj,INDIRECT("'"&proj&"'!B2#"))` to accomodate variable length data but I get a ref error now. Is there anyway I can do to make this work? Adjusted my sample data to reflect the issue with Project 2 running longer and Project 3 starting on a different date. Sample here : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q40hf4lxue2ggrm/Spill%20Net%20Profit%20Data.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I updated the formula on previous link I shared before. The share of input array in `XLOOKUP` has to be the same. So we need to ensure that. I added to approaches. The first one uses `ADDRESS` function. The second one `TOROW`. For the last one you cannot have empty cells in the profit values, you need to put `0`, because empty cell are removed. For the first solution it doesn't matter. I prefer the first one.

Comment: I used the 1st solution which works great in my real data. I've included the final solution at the bottom of my question.